# Expanding Accordion Panel in PrimeFaces with a RadioButton click

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Below is the snapshot of the layout I'm trying to achieve.

I have two questions/problems here:

1. Right now,the page loads with all the accordian panels open. I want it initially to be in the closed state (like in option 1).
2. On click of the Radio button near the tab, the tab should expand. If I click on another radio button, the new tab associated with the radio button should expand, and the other one should close.

[image]

**How do we accomplish this ?**

I don't see any toggle function or anything associated with PrimeFaces accordian. There is only widgetVar.show() function, but it's not helping me.

Comment: According to www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/accordionPanel.jsf , accordian gets first tab open on load. That you can close in javascript by code : `$('#accordian a[tabIndex=-1]:first').click();` For Point 2: js code :`$('input[type=checkbox]').onChange(function(){if($(this).val()){find immediate anchor tag and trigger click on it}})` can be useful.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with your accordion panel tabs closed try setting activeIndex to -1 (or any value that does not correspond to an existing panel). I have not tested this with multiple tabs in an accordion panel, but it should work:

`<p:accordionPanel activeIndex="-1">`